# Por qué el background no se visualiza en css?

Tags: css

***Estoy haciendo un menú:*** y el color de fondo, SOLO SE VE cuando aplico:

```
 overflow:hidden; en **nav > ul**
```

***¿Por qué sucede esto?***

```css
nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}
nav a {text-decoration:none;}

/* Oculto por mientras */
nav ul ul {display:none;}

/* Primer nivel */

nav > ul > li {
  float: left;
}
nav > ul {
  background-color: black;
  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<nav>
<ul id="menu">
  <li><a href="index.html" style="border-right: 2px solid white;">Inicio</a></li>
  <li><a href="computacion.html" style="border-right: 2px solid white;">Computación</a>
  <ul>
  <li><a href="javascript.html" style="border-right: 2px solid white;">Javascript</a></li> 
  <li><a href="fundamentos.html" style="border-right: 2px solid white;">Fundamentos de computación</a></li>  
  </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="computacion.html">Acerca</a></li>
  </ul> 
<ul>                                             
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Porque al setearle `float:left` a los elementos de `li` decendientes inmediatos de `ul` haces que `ul` tenga `height:0`

Esto es debido a que los hijos flotantes (`li`) no afectan el tamaño del contenedor (`ul`)

Teniendo `height:0` el `background-color` simplemente deja de ser visible.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Una manera de resolverlo es lo que has utilizado, otra es cambiar eliminar los elementos flotantes, posicionandolos de otra manera, por ejemplo utilizando `display:inline-block` o `display:flexbox` en su contendor

**inline-block `<li>`**

```css
nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}
nav a {text-decoration:none;}

/* Oculto por mientras */
nav ul ul {display:none;}

/* Primer nivel */

nav > ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
}
nav > ul {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<nav>
<ul id="menu">
  <li><a href="index.html" style="border-right: 2px solid white;">Inicio</a></li>
  <li><a href="computacion.html" style="border-right: 2px solid white;">Computación</a>
  <ul>
  <li><a href="javascript.html" style="border-right: 2px solid white;">Javascript</a></li> 
  <li><a href="fundamentos.html" style="border-right: 2px solid white;">Fundamentos de computación</a></li>  
  </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="computacion.html">Acerca</a></li>
  </ul> 
<ul>                                             
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```

**flex `<ul>`**

```css
nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  display:flex;
}
nav a {text-decoration:none;}

/* Oculto por mientras */
nav ul ul {display:none;}

/* Primer nivel */

nav > ul {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<nav>
<ul id="menu">
  <li><a href="index.html" style="border-right: 2px solid white;">Inicio</a></li>
  <li><a href="computacion.html" style="border-right: 2px solid white;">Computación</a>
  <ul>
  <li><a href="javascript.html" style="border-right: 2px solid white;">Javascript</a></li> 
  <li><a href="fundamentos.html" style="border-right: 2px solid white;">Fundamentos de computación</a></li>  
  </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="computacion.html">Acerca</a></li>
  </ul> 
<ul>                                             
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```